# How to set the connection string for DbProviderFactory connections?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I am trying to use my default connection string for connections but getting:

Access denied for user ''@'172.18.0.1'

No idea what host that is, I've never declared it.

Code:

```
DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("System.Data.MySql", MySqlConnectorFactory.Instance);
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.MySql"));
```

In appsettings.json I have this which I want it to pick up:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=...;User=...;Password=...;Database=...;Allow User Variables=true;",
    "RabbitMq": "amqp://a:b@h:1"
  }
}
```

Comment: do you get this error when running on local machine? is the mysql server running on the same computer as the code? Can you share the connection string with sensitive details masked?

Comment: Yeah the connection string is fine, its after I've switched to using DbProviderFactory rather than my own class. Even trying `serviceCollection.AddTransient<MySqlConnection>(provider => new MySqlConnection(config.GetConnectionString("Default")));` doesn't pick it up.

Comment: I've added it to my question :)

Comment: `DbProviderFactory` is an old .NET 1.0 API; it's not really compatible with DI in ASP.NET Core. The type you want is `MySqlDataSource`, which can be configured via the https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector.DependencyInjection#readme-body-tab package. (Note: currently in beta, but the project author (me) is looking for feedback from real-world users.)